# Chromium can't run starting build 1037194 on M1 Mac

Tags: google-chrome

I'm trying to debug a problem in Chromium and I'm downloading specific builds to test. Works great until I hit a specific build:

- WORKING [Chromium Build 1037170](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Mac/1037170/)
- BROKEN [Chromium Build 1037194](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Mac/1037194/)

These [builds are sequential](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Mac/). Any build after `1037194` I can't run on my M1 Mac. The icon is broken and I get the "You can't open this application because this application is not supported on this Mac."

Any ideas what changed or how I can look at how to run the newer versions of Chromium?

Comment: I have the exact same problem, I will test on a M2 and Intel Mac later this week. If you got past this problem, please share.

Comment: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/mac_arm64.md have some information, I will try to see what Console.app picks up when I try to run Chromium.app